# Form API AJAX refreshes page

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I need to add some AJAX functionality to a node form. Using hook_form_alter I'm overriding form elements. In this particular case I need to add a callback on the 'language' element provided by the translation module (Core, Content Translation).

However, when selecting a different option in the 'language' listbox, the page refreshes. What could trigger this behaviour?

This is the code I'm using:

```
function foo_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'bar_node_form') {
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="bar-form-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['language']['#ajax'] = array(
      'callback' => 'bar_form_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'bar-form-wrapper',
    );

    if (isset($form_state['values'])) {
      drupal_set_message('ajax callback');
    }
  }
}

function bar_form_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this??, I'm facing the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do? Is the page refreshing or the entire $form? What you're asking it to do is by attaching #ajax to the select is that when it changes a value resubmit the entire $form, which would probably include any submit handlers. Typically #ajax would be directed at a form element rather than the entire form.

Comment: The complete page is refreshing.

Comment: So what are you trying to do actually? The callback function should just return the part(s) of the form that you want to update. Why are you returning the entire form?

Comment: I need to change properties of a few form elements.

Comment: Even if I replace/return one element in the callback the page reloads.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. If you get me your whole module I'm happy to try and give it a quick debug.

Answer (score 1):

since the callback is acting as a form submit, your callback (_submit) should have the same naming convention as your form id.

"bar_node_form" is your form id so:

```
'callback' => 'bar_node_form_submit',
```

Answer (score -1):

When you specify `'callback' => 'bar_form_callback'`, it's not referring to a PHP callback per se. **Callback** in this case refers to a `hook_menu()` callback, in other words, the URL that JavaScript will call when the AJAX trigger is fired.

You need to define a `bar_form_callback` path in your custom_module_menu() function. That menu callback then call `function bar_form_callback()`.

[D.O. FAPI reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax).

Comment: As explained in my question, adding AJAX to the form is what I intend to do. "What could trigger this behaviour?" is a question on what causes the page to reload (yes, a hard reload). The page reloads when I select a language in the select box.

Comment: Hopefully it's just that you're missing the hook_menu() callback.

Comment: I don't think you need a hook_menu() defined for the #ajax callbacks.

Comment: I think you do. Else, how is Drupal going to find your function? I doubt there's some automagical behavior for that. Also check your Firebug. When you click on the languages button, what is the XHR (AJAX) callback path? Probably is thenameofyoursite.com/bar_form_callback.

Comment: Also, check your PHP error log and the Drupal watchdog. It might have been throwing an error. "Hard" reload is not supposed to be the normal behavior, so one can only assume there's an error involved. I think again your error is that you're missing the AJAX callback (the hook_menu implementation).

Comment: Malks is right, you don't need hook_menu defined for an #ajax callback.

Comment: What path in the Drupal site is JavaScript calling? What PHP function is handling that message. There's a PHP callback somewhere getting the message from JavaScript's XHR, and something tells me it's not your PHP function. If you do a `error_log('foo bar baz');` on your PHP callback, what happens? Does "foo bar baz" appear on your error log?

Comment: #ajax is handled by a drupal defined callback. Part of its reason for existing is to save the coder the effort of having to define a callback manually.

Comment: Good. I'm curious though, is your PHP function getting called?

Comment: ['#ajax']['callback'] refers to a callback in your module, not to a hook_menu implementation